# Ionic application (SMS verification link)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Is there a way that i can generate a link and sent it to the user via sms, that can access my **ionic** application to verify his account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at something like the `cordova-universal-links-plugin`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin). I am not sure whether this would work from an SMS and could not find any information on that, but I am guessing that any links send in an SMS can be opened in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i will look at it and give you my feedback